# Как с помощью openpyxl скопировать данные в др книгу в определенное место (ячейку)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как не просто скопировать столбец с данными в другую книгу Excel, а именно скопировать в определенный столбец, начиная с определенной ячейки.

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Документ_1.xlsx')
ws=wb['лист_1']
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('Документ_2.xlsx')
ws2=wb2['лист_из_др_книги']

for row in ws['D4':'D24']:
    for cell in row:
        listA=[]
        listA.append(cell.value)
        ws2.append(listA)
wb2.save(filename='Документ_2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример - копируем все значения из столбца `D` в (`c:/temp/1.xlsx` - `Sheet1`) в файл: `c:/temp/2.xlsx`, лист: `Sheet2` так чтобы в выходном файле первое значение попало в ячейку `D4`, второе в `D5` и т.д.:

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/temp/1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/temp/2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Sheet2']

target_cell_num = 4

for i,cell in enumerate(ws1['D']):  # читаем все значения из столбца `D`
    ws2[f'D{target_cell_num + i}'] = cell.value

wb2.save(filename='c:/temp/2.xlsx')
```

Comment: @user327535, я использую [документированный метод: `ws['D4'] = value`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell). Просто адрес ячейки задается динамически...